# How to return raw data from view?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have function which generates data for xml and I want to use a template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
    {% for item in items %}
    <item>
        <title>{{ item.title }}</title>
        <desc>{{ item.desc }}</desc>
    </item>
    {% endfor %}
</items>
```

But if I use:

```
t = loader.get_template(templatename)
c = RequestContext(request, generated_data)
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

I getting result:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <items>
               <item>
                   <title>Title 1</title>
                   <desc>desc 1</desc>
               </item>
               <item>
                   <title>Title 2</title>
                   <desc>desc 2</desc>
               </item>
               <item>
                   <title>Title 3</title>
                   <desc>desc 3</desc>
               </item>
          </items>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to prevent from this header?

Comment: What do you mean by `< ... my result ...>`? What is appearing there?

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this extraneous HTML?

Comment: I dont think you actually dealing with a problem. Point is that browser automaticaly add all that _unwanted_ code during you inspect page, while in fact your code has no `html`, `head` or `body` tags.

Answer (score 0):

My fault, special chars in source, close please.